# How to organize 3rd-party libraries for Python?

Tags: python, programming, source-code

I am new in Python. I want to install many 3rd-party libraries (I think they are also called packages?) like, for example, "AstroPy". But I am not sure where the new source code will be stored (I mean, the new ".py" text files that will be downloaded and will contain the Python functions of "AstroPy").

I would like to keep track of all the libraries that I will install. Is there any way to do that for Python?

I used to use IDL and when I want to install a library, I am used to simply download all the text files containing the IDL scripts and then store them in a folder like "/IDL/libraries". That way, I could easily see what I had and also easily uninstall them.

Comment: Why not use `pip`, the package manager for Python? It should already be installed along with recent versions of Python, but if not, you can install it as per https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the location of **global site-packages** (dist-packages that may have been installed via `easy_install` or [`pip`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/), a Python package manager) by running:

```
python -m site
```

If the package was installed using **`pip`**, you can find the location of a specific package (for example, `name`) by running:

```
pip show name
```

Finally, **per-user (local) site-packages** can be found by running:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

You can find slightly more information about dist-packages versus site-packages on the [Debian wiki page for Python](https://wiki.debian.org/Python).